# Не открывается локальный сайт на Линукс

Tags: linux, flask, localhost

Пишу бота на питоне. Запустил Фласк, по адресу localhost:5000 на пк с линукс открывается страница, которую он формирует. Однако при попытке открыть эту страницу через локалку по ip:5000 вылетает ошибка: Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Помогите советом, подскажите, что делать…

Comment: брандмауэр отключен

Comment: По-хорошему, принято в качестве веб-сервера использовать отдельную софтину (в настоящее время чаще всего это nginx), которая принимает запросы и передаёт их серверу приложения (в вашем случае это flask). Но если уж очень хочется: `run(host=0.0.0.0,…)`

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev это конечно оффтоп, но `в настоящее время чаще всего это nginx`. Давайте поделимся статистикой. Есть, например, вот [такое](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2018/09/24/september-2018-web-server-survey.html). nginx из года в год показывает стабильный рост, но под определение "чаще всего" пока еще не подходит. Из [прошлогоднего](https://habr.com/post/326248/). Да, есть у nginx региональные предпочтения, но в целом это опять таки не "чаще всего". А еще бывает так, что Apache стоит за nginx-ом...

Comment: @de_frag OK, OK, "среди меня чаще всего это nginx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю сервер запущен слушать на **localhost:5000**, 
но ты питаешься получить доступ к нему из другого устройства в подсети. 
Но это действительно не сработает.

Проблема в том что когда ты говоришь серверу слушать какой-то адрес, это значит принимать соединения с интерфейса который связан с этим адресом. **127.0.0.1** назначен интерфейсу **loopback** (lo при выводе ip addr), и предназначен для работы внутри устройства.

Но если необходимо предоставить доступ не только устройству необходимо изменит интерфейс, простейший вариант слушать **0.0.0.0:5000**, это дефолтный хост, все запросы необработанные определенным интерфейсом в конце концов попадут туда, доступ в таком случае можно получит с устройства, из локальной сети и даже из Интернета.

Но если необходимо ограничить доступ только для локальной сети, тогда надо слушать на адресе из этой сети, напимер **192.168.0.10:5000**, или что-то в этом духе, в зависимости от IP-адреса локальной сети.

Comment: @TenDal Благодарю!